# Item replacement in ObservableCollection doesn't update WPF ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, binding, observablecollection

I have (I thought) a fairly conventional WPF app.

I've

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" ...
```

MyList is an

```
ObservableCollection<MyItem>
```

MyItem does not implement `INotifiyPropertyChanged`

when I `Add` items to the OC, the UI updates with out issue.
When I **replace** items, via

```
MyList[index] = newItem;
```

the UI only updates occasionally.
**Sometimes** selecting another control on the window helps, but often not.Updates are arriving at about 5 per second. If it matters, this is WPF 4 on a Win7 x64 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes absolutely no sense to me, replacements are registered by ObservableCollections and i had no problems with it so far...

I suspect the error lies somwhere else.

e.g. accidentally replacing the item with itself, destroying the binding to the data, things like that...

On a sidenote, if you ever encounter behaviour that occurs *sometimes* the error is quite likely to be in your own code logic because *sometimes* points toward indeterministic behaviour which you normally should not encounter in any decent framework.

Comment: I discovered the issue, the replacement item was different, but had the same GetHashCode()

Comment: Oh, that's quite an unfortunate thing to come by, quite hard to notice  i imagine.

Answer (score 3):

My guess it that you better use `Remove()` and `Insert(index, item)` instead of assigning to an indexed item. Removing and inserting items must raise the CollectionChanged delegate.

Comment: No, this should make no difference at all, `CollectionChanged` also takes note of replacements.

Comment: That might be the case but i would not leave it at that, you might be masking an error if you just do it that way (unless of course this actually is a bug in WPF)

Comment: H.B - good point. Any suggestions on where to look? I've confirmed that it isn't a threading issue, in that the update to the collection is using the main Dispatcher.